# Using a Function handle in Matlab

Tags: matlab, function, handler

I would like to use knnimpute to fill some missing values in my dataset. Thing is, I would like to use my own distance function, instead of the typical ones (Euclidean, Manhattan...).

For what I've read, `knnimpute` allows me to use a function handle, that calculates the distance according to [Heterogeneous Euclidean-Overlap Metric (HEOM)](http://axon.cs.byu.edu/~randy/jair/wilson2.html)

I've implemented this function as a regular function, but not as a handle function. So, I cannot use the distance matrix from my "normal" function, because this has to be done inside `knnimpute`, somehow, as a handler...

I'm confuse, can someone help me understand what I need to do?

Comment: Does the documentation not give you what you're looking for? http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/function_handle.html

Comment: The documentation for `knnimput` points you to `pdist`, which explains the form your function needs to take http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/pdist.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as your implementation of a distance function has the same signature as the standard distance functions, then you should be able to easily pass your function in.

From the **knnimpute** documentation ([matlab knnimpute](http://www.mathworks.com/help/bioinfo/ref/knnimpute.html)) it states that you can pass "*A handle to a distance function, specified using @, for example, @distfun.*"  It then refers the reader to the **pdist** function which provides more details ([matlab pdist](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/pdist.html)) about the custom distance function:

*A distance function specified using @: 
D = pdist(X,@distfun)
**A distance function must be of form
d2 = distfun(XI,XJ)**
taking as arguments a 1-by-n vector XI, corresponding to a single row of X, and an m2-by-n      matrix XJ, corresponding to multiple rows of X. distfun must accept a matrix XJ with an arbitrary number of rows. distfun must return an m2-by-1 vector of distances d2, whose kth element is the distance between XI and XJ(k,:).*

So as long as your distance function, as defined in your *.m file matches this signature and so can support these inputs, then there shouldn't be any problems.

Suppose that your distance function is in the **mydistFunc.m** file, and it's signature matches the above requirements, then all you should need to do is:

```
% call knnimpute with the data and your function
knnimpute(inputData,'Distance',@mydistFunc);
```

Comment: pdist(X), if X has some NaNs, returns NaN as well. I've read the knnimpute documentation, but is does not say how knnimpute deals with distances between observations that are NaN. So, in this function, mydistFunc, should I consider that whenever an observation has a NaN, the distance between the that and other observation is NaN? This doesn't seem right to me, but seems like the standard procedure in pdist...